# iOS/Android - How to control users in social app?

Tags: android, ios

I have an anonymous mobile social app and I want to know what kind of measures I need to take, in order to "control" my users!

Let's say someone posts something illegal... (thankfully hasn't happened yet) All I need is their IP or do I need something more?

Right now all I do is keeping their deviceToken, so I can ban them among any of their multiple accounts they may have.

**EDIT:** What I'm actually asking is what kind of data should I obtain from the user's device, so that the user can be identified if needed?

Comment: don't think this is an android and/or ios question really, if anything it is probably a server related question. depends on how you register and allow users on your app really, your question needs more specifics IMO :)

Comment: I'm actually asking what kind of data should I obtain from the user's device, so that the user can be identified if needed

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get the IMEI number from Android devices and others also like (IMEI on GSM, MEID for CDMA).

Each Android device has unique id when its first-time boot that id also you can get and IMEI number is best to track the user.

Answer (score 1):

> What I'm actually asking is what kind of data should I obtain from the user's device, so that the user can be identified if needed?

Once a **user can be identified if needed**, your app is not **anonymous** anymore.

You need to decide whether you are trying to moderate users, or content. Both of these are very difficult tasks, and as one comment on your question says:

> don't think this is an android and/or ios question really, if anything it is probably a server related question. depends on how you register and allow users on your app really

If you you are moderating content, your need to build mechanisms to delete or mark specific posts/comments as illegal, so they are not visible anymore. Obviously this needs to be, or much better, done on a server, not in a mobile app.

If you are trying to moderate users, let them identify themselves, by logging in. Firstly, because it is wrong to track users when they think their participation is anonymous. Secondly, because, any other tracking mechanism (device ids etc), is not fool proof. All a user has to do to overcome your **ban**, is uninstall the app, reset the device, or just continue to do the same thing from another device.

Comment: The content moderation is taken care of! The user moderation is what concerns me... I'm not interested on the users' identity, as long as they don't do anything illegal! Let's think of this fictional scenario... a user systematically sells drugs on the app and say the police ask me to give them his/her identity. Shouldn't I have something to give? I really don't think something like that would ever happen, but I feel I should be prepared in case it did!

`let them identify themselves, by logging in.` How would a user be identified just by logging in?

Comment: `How would a user be identified just by logging in?` -> not identify as a person, but identity within the scope of your app / platform. So all their activity can be tied to this one user identity.

Comment: `police ask me to give them his/her identity` -> if you think your application has potential for such a case, you not only need to make the user create an account, and login, but also to verify the account by some background information/document

Comment: The users already signup/login to the app, but without providing any personal info... we only ask for username, password and optionally email. Storing some IP wouldn't be enough?

Comment: Oh wait, that changes things. In your question you say your app is ** anonymous**, but, if your users **log in** to your app, **AND** content moderation, is already taken care of, all you need is a good **"Terms of Service"**, and **"Privacy Policy"** which are available for the user to read, and optionally accepted by user with a checkmark during registration, and you are done. Beyond this any legal stuff will be country / locality specific so consult good lawyers on what you **NEED** to do, and then check the `how to do it` part.

Comment: Also, since you mention users, **log in** to your app, it makes it much easier for you to send, and store all kinds of data, like device ids, ips etc on your server against a user identity, when the app makes an API call. Of course, you should take user consent and let the users know you are collecting this in data, clearly in privacy policy. All unique device tokens, and ips for each user should be more than enough just for the sake of book keeping.

Comment: Perfect! That's what I needed to know! Thank you very much!